# What is sun.awt.windows.WToolkit?

Tags: java, event-handling, awt

I have the following piece of code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class QueueTest {
static int i=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, 

InvocationTargetException {
        EventQueue eventQueue = 

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
        eventQueue.push(new MyEventQueue());


    Frame f=new Frame();
    f.setSize(400,400);
    //f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocation(150,150);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setVisible(true);

    Button b=new Button("button");
    //b.setEnabled(false);
    f.add(b);
/*
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
        System.out.println("button is clicked");
        }
    });
*/
    }

    private static class MyEventQueue extends EventQueue {
        public void postEvent(AWTEvent theEvent) {
//            System.out.println("Event Posted");
  System.out.println("The source of event is "+theEvent.getSource());
            super.postEvent(theEvent);
        }

    protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event)
    {
    System.out.println("The source of event ("+(i++)+") is 

"+event.getSource());
    super.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    }
}
```

In the output i could sometimes see

`The source of event is (78) sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@77ef83`

when I think i have only two sources, the `java.awt.Button` and the `java.awt.Frame`. Also when I am pressing the mouse, I could see two events being generated for which one is `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit` is the source and for the other is `Button` (when I clicked on button).

My questions are

1. what is sun.awt.windows.WToolkit?
2. why am I able to see two events on a single mouse press?

Comment: Consider using `swing` instead of `AWT` to program a GUI. [Why Swing is better than AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt#answer-408830)

Comment: By the way, even Swing is in maintenance-mode. If you are a beginner learning to do GUIs in Java, consider the successor to Swing: JavaFX/OpenJFX.

Answer (score 3):

The names speak for themselves: `AWT` stands for [*Abstract Window Toolkit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) which implies that the `Toolkit` is `abstract` and requires an actual implementation. `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit` is such an implementation for the *Microsoft Windows* plattform hence the `W` in its name. On other operating systems you will see different implementations, e.g. `sun.awt.X11.XToolkit` on *Linux*. If you just do a `System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit());` you will see that the `Toolkit`’s string representation matches that of the event source which you see from time to time.

I suggest you do a `print` of the entire event instead of just the source. Then you will see what these events are for. You will see what kind of events the toolkit generates. And you will see that a mouse click can generate up to three events: one for the press, one for the release and one if pressing and releasing happened at the same location which is considered a *click*.

Comment: Ok. But I wasn't able to understand how is it showed as an event source?

Comment: I would also add that `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit` is an implementation for the Window platform on Windows. If you run that code on linux you get `sun.awt.X11.XToolkit`, which is the same thing but changes name according to the window manager :)

Comment: Nice. When press and release happened at the same time, it is considered a click. Who detects it as a click? The logical device driver for mouse?

Comment: @JavaTechnical The button is painted on the `Frame`, so if you click it you also click on the frame :) If you don't want the frame to fire that event, attach an `ActionListener` to the `Button` instead of extending system event queue

Comment: Ok. Here as the event is not controlled by the Button, the event moved up the hierarchy to the Frame?

Comment: @JavaTechnical I think so, but I'm not sure. It's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: That means the AWT 1.0 Delegation model is followed if a listener is not added to the Button to detect that event?

Comment: @JavaTechnical you really should start looking at the *type* of the event before starting speculations. There are more than just mouse events.

Comment: @JavaTechnical: As already said, just do a `System.out.println(theEvent);` instead of just printing the source only. Then you will start to understand, well hopefully. The events having the toolkit source are *not* mouse events.

Comment: I've found InvocationEvent being generated by the GlobalCursorManager on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit. I came to know that the GlobalCursorManager gets a component at a particular mouse point. But I didn't understand the role of the WToolkit. What is meant by **on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit**

Comment: You already know that. The Toolkit is the source of the event. Don’t try to interpret further meaning to it. The source is just a property of the event.

Comment: Ok. But why is WToolkit a source here? A `Button` is a source when mouse is pressed on it or some action is performed on it. But where is WToolkit in my program? How has it been the source?

Comment: It’s an object. It (or one of its helper objects) did create that event instance and so it is specified as the source of the event. It’s really simple. It’s really meaningless. There could be *any* object stored as the event’s source. The reason why a source is provided is because events insist on having a source. I really don’t get what your problem is. Are you trying to add philosophical meaning to the event source?

Comment: Ok that means the source here need not necessarily be a component object. Right?

Comment: @JavaTechnical: That’s right, the source of an `AWTEvent` does not need to be a `Component`. There is a subclass of it, `ComponentEvent`, which is used for events regarding a single `Component`. It consequently offers the source already cast to `Component` via [`getComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent()). Note that [`ContainerEvent`, `FocusEvent`, `InputEvent`, `PaintEvent`, `WindowEvent` are sub-classes of `ComponentEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-tree.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing ALL of the libraries by using the * character.  So the output specifies where the source of event occurred.

Comment: Could you elaborate it?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Please refer to the **official** java documentation. [java.awt.Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html)

Comment: what is meant by all actual implementations of AWT?